# Split column values and then re-join them SQL

Tags: sql

I have run into the following problem.

I have a table where a column contains different values that I want to separate, for example, REGION and LEGAL ENTITY. (see table 1)

All regions are also available for each unique LEGAL ENTITY.

If I have two legal entities and three regions, there must be a total of six rows. (Se output)

I am thinking about creating two new tables and then using left join on 1=1. But I would like to avoid creating two tables, does anyone know a better solution?

Table1

| Obj_type | obj_id |
| --- | --- |
| REGION | 1 |
| REGION | 2 |
| REGION | 3 |
| LE (legal entity) | LE1 |
| LE (legal entity) | LE2 |

Output:

| obj_id | obj_id |
| --- | --- |
| LE1 | 1 |
| LE1 | 2 |
| LE1 | 3 |
| LE2 | 1 |
| LE2 | 2 |
| LE2 | 3 |

Answer (score 0):

In this case, CROSS JOINing two SELECT statements should do the job:

```
select * from
(select obj_id from table1 where obj_type = 'REGION')
cross join
(select obj_id from table1 where obj_type = 'LE (legal entity)');
```